# Rugarch using Fourier series as external regressors

Tags: r, regression, fft, external

I am trying to replicate Campbell and Diebold's (2005) ARMA-GARCH model for temperature. I wrote the following piece of code:

```
garch.spec = ugarchspec(
  variance.model = list(
    model= 'sGARCH', 
    garchOrder = c(1,1), 
    external.regressors = extreg.garch),
  mean.model = list(
    armaOrder = c(3,0),
    external.regressors = extreg.arma, 
    include.mean = T), 
  distribution.model = "sstd", 
  fixed.pars = list(omega = 0))
```

Respectively, `extreg.garch` and `extreg.arma` are:

```
fourier = ts(fourier(temp, K = 2), start = c(1989,1,1), frequency = 365)
extreg.arma  = matrix(cbind(t,fourier[,1],fourier[,2],fourier[,3],fourier[,4]), ncol = 5)
extreg.garch = matrix(cbind(fourier[,1],fourier[,1],fourier[,1],fourier[,3]), ncol = 4)
```

The problem I have is that all coefficients for `extreg.garch` are `0.000`. If someone could clarify what I am doing wrong I'd really appreciate it!

Also, is the command `fixed.pars = list(omega = 0)` equivalent to omitting the constant in the GARCH equation?

Thanks in advance for any help!